# Creating a GUI for my program

Tags: python, user-interface

I am trying to create a GUI for my encoding program in Python. The issue is it doesn't seem to work simultaneously. I am a beginner at using Python so I am not sure how everything work just yet. I looked for solutions on the internet already but I got nothing.

The program I have so far is

```
def program (str,my_fn):
    global i
    i=0
    while i<len(str):
        my_fn()
        i += 1

def encrypt(my_result,str,number=0):
    my_result.append(ord(str[i])-number)
def decrypt(my_result,str,number=0):
    my_result.append(chr(str[i]+number))
def password_generator():
    password = input("What would the password be:\n")
    numerical_password=[]
    program(password,partial(encrypt,numerical_password,password))
    global code
    code = sum(numerical_password)

while choice != "Exit":
    choice = input("Do you want to Encrypt, Decrypt,  or Exit?\n")
    if choice == "Encrypt": #Encrypt
        option = input("Do you want a password?(Yes or No)\n")
        if option == "Yes":
            password_generator()
        else:
            code = 0

        answer = input("What would you like to encrypt:\n")
        message = []
        program(answer,partial(encrypt,message,answer,code))
        print (message)



    if choice == "Decrypt": #Decrypt
        option = input("Do you have a password?(Yes or No)\n")
        code= 0 
        if option == "Yes":
            password_generator()
        else:
            code = 0
        answer = [int(x) for x in input("(Please insert ONLY intergers seperated with commas)\nWhat would you like to decrypt:\n").split(",")]
        text =[]
        program(answer, partial(decrypt,text,answer,code))
        print("".join(text))
print("ThAnK yOu foR uSiNg eNcodER. HAve a nICe dAY!")
```

So far I  have figured out how to add some buttons to a user Interface. I plan on adding a display and a text input box later but right now I just want to focus on linking the GUI and the program.

from tkinter import *

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Note Taker")
root.geometry("250x250")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

def Button1():
    choice =="Encrypted"




button1 = Button(root, text="button1", command=Button1)
button1.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

My goal is so when Button1 is pressed it will allow the user to encrypt their desired string.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think Easygui might be handy for u. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easygui

Answer (score 0):

Technically, for simultaneous execution one should use [threads](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html), but this wouldn't fit your code very well. I would suggest turning the main body of code into a function. This should be very simple. Instead of:

```
while choice != "Exit":
    choice = input("Do you want to Encrypt, Decrypt,  or Exit?\n")
    ...
```

write

```
def make_choice(choice = None):
    if choice is None:
        choice = input("Do you want to Encrypt, Decrypt,  or Exit?\n")
    ...
```

This should fix your problem; just replace `choice == "Encrypted"` with `make_choice("Encrypted")` or whatever choice you require. Hope this helps!

Comment: So will I put the function inside the loop that creates the GUI?

Comment: Sorry; didn't clarify that. You should replace `def Button1(): choice =="Encrypted"` with `def Button1(): make_choice("Encrypted")`, with `Encrypted` replaced in other buttons corresponding to whaatever function you want them to perform.